# Inconsistant date parsing with missing timezone

Tags: javascript, date, datetime

In doing some testing I've found inconsistant behavior between browsers with the following javascript

```
new Date("2013-09-10T08:00:00").toString()
```

In IE and Firefox the result is

> "Tue Sep 10 2013 08:00:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)"

In Chrome the result is

> "Tue Sep 10 2013 04:00:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)"

So according to my reading of the [ECMA](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-262.pdf) script of the format for Date strings it says...

> All numbers must be base 10. If the MM or DD fields are absent "01" is
>   used as the value. If the HH, mm, or ss  fields are absent "00" is
>   used as the value and the value of an absent sss field is "000".
>   **The value of an absent time zone offset is "Z"**

However in the documentation for the "new Date()" constructor it says

> 15.9.3.2 new Date (value)
>
> 1. Let v be ToPrimitive(value).
> 2. If Type(v) is String, then
>
>    a. Parse v as a date, in exactly the same manner as for the parse method (15.9.4.2); let V be the time 
>      value for this date.
>
> 15.9.4.2 Date.parse (string)
>
> The parse function applies the ToString operator to its argument and interprets the resulting String as a date
>   and time; it returns a Number, the UTC time value corresponding to the
>   date and time. The String **may be interpreted as a local time**, a UTC
>   time, or a time in some other time zone, depending on the contents of
>   the  String.

Any ideas which implementation is correct?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Standards clash. ISO 8601 [states that](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Time_zone_designators):

> If no UTC relation information is given with a time representation, the time is assumed to be in local time.

ECMA [says](http://es5.github.io/#x15.9.1.15):

> The value of an absent time zone offset is “Z”.

Mozilla devs [think](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=647568) that ISO takes precedence, Chrome folks seem to disagree.

The [current draft of ES6](http://wiki.ecmascript.org/doku.php?id=harmony%3aspecification_drafts) says (under 20.3.1.15):

> If the time zone offset is absent, the date-time is interpreted as a local time.

so Mozilla's implementation is (will be) correct.

Comment: Chrome seems to have swapped to the ISO definition now.

Answer (score 1):

There are several questions on stackoverflow.com that address this issue. I gave a rather thorough explanation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2587345/javascript-date-parse/20463521#20463521) if anyone reading this is interested in the browser-to-browser details.

The bottom line though is, for now at least, you should either avoid the ISO 8601 format all together or ALWAYS include a timezone specifier when using it. And, never use the 'YYYY-MM-dd' format because it gets interpreted as a short version of ISO 8601 without a time zone specifier.